# Making a string pattern

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to get the following code to behave as follows:

pattern(4):

```
1
1*2
1**3
1***4
```

```
function pattern(n){
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  output[i] = "1" + (Array(n-1).join("*")).toString() + n.toString();
 }

return output;
}
```

That's what I have currently. I'm getting a blank return when I run the code. Can someone point me in the right direction here? Thank you!

Example test class: Test.assertEquals(pattern(3),"1\n1*2\n1**3");

Comment: you have `output` being a string: `output=""`, strings are immutable in javascript, meaning you cannot change any part of it in place, eg `output[3]="a"`, you have to make a new string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a couple of changes and slightly modified the logic.

1. Let output be an array instead of string.
2. Start iteration from `i =1` instead of `i=0`. We need the first value as `1`
3. When `i==1` , the output will be only `1`
4. `"1" + (Array(i).join("*")).toString() + i.toString());` 
    `Array(i).join('*')` will concat `*`,`i` times & `i.toString()` with `1`
   In your code you it is `(Array(n-1).join("*")).toString() + n.toString();`
   which I believe will always `n` as last digit. So everytime output will be `1**n`

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
function pattern(n){
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
  if(i==1){
   output.push("1")
  }
  else if(i>1){
    output.push("1" + (Array(i).join("*")).toString() + i.toString());
 }
 }

return output;
}
var m = pattern(5);
console.log(m.join('\n'));
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/nx6ne6et/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your response! This was very helpful. I ended up with the final code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Wahoowa14/vbsz2x6a/

Will you explain why output.join("\n") works? I don't quite understand what's going on there.

Comment: @wahoowa it is creating new line

Answer (score 2):

`output` can be an array, and you could be pushing the new items onto it.

```
function pattern(n){
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    output.push("1" + (Array(n-1).join("*")).toString() + n.toString());
  }
  return output;
}
```

The output of the function will be an array, which you should be able to join back together using a new line

```
var output = pattern(4);
console.log(output.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note:

- As @PatrickEvans has stated, strings in JS are immutable, so trying to modify character elements within the string does not work.
- The pattern of increasing asterisks `*` and numbers at the end of each string require not the static `n`, but the incrementing `i`.

Here are two ways you can do it, though I suggest the latter.

**String concatenation:**

```js
function pattern(n){
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!i) output = "1"; 
    else output += "\n1" + (Array(i+1).join("*")).toString() + (i+1).toString();
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(pattern(4));
```

**Array join:**

```js
function pattern(n) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!i) output.push("1"); 
    else output.push("1" + (Array(i+1).join("*")).toString() + (i+1).toString());
    // ES6: else output.push(`1${'*'.repeat(i)}${i+1}`);
  }
  return output.join('\n');
}

console.log(pattern(4));
```